# Is it possible to change the click behavior on the launchers? Left click on a launcher opens the right click menu

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, menu

My launcher consists of a few icons, with about 5 applications in the right click menu of each icon.  If possible, I'd like to change the behavior of clicking on these icons.

Instead of right clicking to get the menu, I'd like to left click, and get the menu that you normally get by right clicking the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With a little creativity**

You can make a left click on the launcher icon behave as a right click.

You mention you have five applications availbale on right-click. I assume you created or edited the quicklists (desktop files) yourself, and added the application shortcuts. I also assume you do not need or use its *native* command anymore, since it would result in a strange behaviour of the launcher; launching one application and at the same time offering a menu to choose another...

The solution I suggest uses the desktop file's *native* command to simulate right clicking on the icon.

**The solution**

The solution is icon specific, so not the *general* behaviour of the Unity Launcher will change, only of the icon of which you prepared the .desktop file.

1. Install `xdotool`, (it is in the repositories) with which you can simulate keyboard and mouse actions.
2. Then replace the desktop file's (first) `Exec=` line by:

   ```
   Exec=xdotool click 3
   ```

Then, when you click on the icon in the launcher with left click, it behaves as right-click and shows you the quicklist items you created in the .desktop file.

**Cosmetic difference with a "real" right-click**

Usually, when you start an application by (left) clicking on its launcher, it is blinking for a few seconds, as a "time out" for the icon before you can reuse it. Although you *can* use items from the menu immediately, before you can *reuse* it, the icon has a time out of a few seconds just like it would have when starting an application from its *native* command. That would be a bit annoying if you would like to quickly start more than one application from the icon's shortcuts.

To limit the visual effect of the time out, you can set the desktop's `StartupNotify=true` to `StartupNotify=false`, so the "turning wheel" will not appear.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thanks.  Before, the Exec= line just made a notification saying 'NO' so this is perfect.  Is there also a way to make the right click launch an application, so that the two clicks are essentially flipped?

Comment: @DrewDiezel That would be a bit more difficult, since what happens on *left click*, is determined in the desktop file (even if it simulates right click), but what happens on *right click* is a property of the Unity launcher. I noticed a small inconvenience by the way, see my edited answer, hope it will not bother you too much.

Comment: I assume `StartupNotify` is in the `.desktop` file.  After setting it to false, the wheel is gone, however the timeout is still there.  Your fix was just to remove the visual cue, correct?  It appears there is still a timeout, forcing me to wait before the icon is clicked again.

Comment: @DrewDiezel the fix was indeed only the visual effect, which I found a bit ugly itself. I am afraid the time out is unavoidable, although I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: that works good enough, thanks! This is pretty much the functionality I was going for.